# What is the source of symmetry in this recurrence plot of the Circle map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I was reading about the Circle map in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_tongue) Wikipedia entry. 
This is a dynamical map with a single variable $\theta$, and dynamics defined by 
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n + \Omega -\frac{K}{2\pi} \sin (2\pi \theta_n)$$

The entry features the following plot of the recurrence time as a function of the two parameters

[image: Circle]

Where $\Omega$ varies from 0 to 1 along the $x$-axis, and $K$ varies from 0 at the bottom to $4\pi$ at the top. The redder the color, the longer the recurrence time.

Where does the symmetry of the plot reflected along $\Omega = \frac{1}{2}$ come from? Is it something that is evident from the equation?

Comment: This family is called the standard (or Arnold) family, there is a lot of literature on it. The symmetry comes from the fact that the map with parameters $\Omega$ and $K$ is conjugate to the map with parameters $-\Omega$ and $K$ by $\theta \mapsto -\theta$. Obviously integer translations are also symmetries, so $\Omega \mapsto 1-\Omega$ leaves recurrence times unchanged.

Comment: @LukasGeyer That's a good explanation. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I now notice that it is not completely symmetrical. At about two thirds of the way down the colors are Blue/Green on the top of the left/right legs of the X, respectively.